# Why does rvest pull empty data when inclosed in loop?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape hotel reviews from a certain hotel on from tripadvisor. I'm using Rvest to accomplish my goal. This script has to scrape multiple pages.

When executing my script rvest sometimes returns vectors with empty values when executing in a loop. This is completely random. Does anyone have a fix for this?

I tried manually walking trough the script. When i slowly go trough it it works most of the time, but sometimes still manages to pull empty data.

```
# Webscrapen
df <- data.frame()
x = 0

for(i in 1:250){
  url <- paste("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g295424-d7760386-Reviews-or",x,"-Hyatt_Regency_Dubai_Creek_Heights-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html", sep = "")
  x = x + 5

  reviews <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('.common-text-ReadMore__content--2X4LR') %>%
    html_node('.hotels-hotel-review-community-content-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--2OVqJ span') %>%
    html_text()

  rating <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(".hotels-hotel-review-community-content-review-list-parts-RatingLine__bubbles--3d2Be span") %>%
    html_attr("class")

  rating <- sapply(strsplit(rating, "_"), `[`, 4) %>% 
    as.numeric()

  if(nrow(df) == 0){
    df <- data.frame(reviews[!is.na(reviews)], rating, stringsAsFactors = F)
  } else {
    temp <- df
    df <- rbind(temp, data.frame(reviews[!is.na(reviews)], rating, stringsAsFactors = F))
  }
}
```

I expect to scrape all the reviews till my for loop stops. I should have a dataframe of at least 100 reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround by placing the review in a repeat loop and keep repeating as long as the vector hasn't been filled.

The code takes a bit longer to execute but it gets the job done.

```
  repeat{
    Review <- url %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes('.common-text-ReadMore__content--2X4LR') %>%
      html_node('.hotels-hotel-review-community-content-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--2OVqJ span') %>%
      html_text()
    if(length(Review) >= 1 ){
      break;
    }
  }
```